# Deploy contracts without deploying Migrations

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I would like to deploy my contracts to mainnet using truffle. I figure it's the easiest and safest way to do it since I already deploy to testnet using truffle. The problem is I don't want to deploy the Migrations contract for every repository I have because it adds up to too much money. At today's ETH prices it's about $1.60 per deploy, I'd rather pay 0. How do I deploy my contracts to mainnet using truffle without deploying the Migrations contract?

Actually it looks like I can simply comment out the deployment of Migrations.sol in 1_initial_migration.js. What are the consequences of doing this? Will I run into problems by doing this?

Comment: I'd use my own migrations scripts.